# ember cli (1.13) ember table plugin

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember table plugin. In the previous version of ember cli 0.2 ember table hello world example works well but in new version of ember cli(1.13) it is not working, it shows many deprecation warnings and one error that

**Property set failed: object in path "tableComponent" could not be found or was destroyed**

> error details
>
> Deprecations were detected, see the Ember Inspector deprecations tab
>   for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The current release `ember-table 0.9.0` works with `ember-cli 0.2.7` and `ember 1.12`.

Release for `ember 1.13` (and so for `ember-cli 1.13`) is still in development. See this conversation for details https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/issues/337.